# Значение слова «та» (не местоимения)

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, частица, разговорная-речь

Есть ли где-то в справочниках описание слова «та»? Хотелось бы найти информацию, где бы подробно рассматривались его функции, особенно в тех случаях, когда «та» стоит в начале предложения.
Пример: «Как дела?» — «Та нормально». Интересно, какой смысловой оттенок прибавляет «та» к фразе?

Comment: В украинском есть такое, поэтому можно поискать в каких-то диалектах русского. Только это частица, а не междометие. То же, что в русском "да" в подобном значении (подробное описание можете посмотреть по частице "да" у Кузнецова, если этого Вам будет достаточно).

Comment: @grizzly спасибо. Исправил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что "та" по смыслу и употреблению равно [**ДА**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%B0), в нашем случае — это ***усилительная частица***, которая использована в начале предложения для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности.

*— Как дела?

— Та* [= да] *нормально!*

В словаре русских народных говоров (стр. 197):
**1.** [**Та**](https://iling.spb.ru/dictionaries/srng/43.pdf), союз и частица.

1. Соединительный союз. Да, и. *Постукатят в окошко та утикают.*
2. Противительный союз. Но. *Та коров у нас чи нет. Я тебе сколько ждала, та не дождалась.*
3. Утвердительная частица. **Да**. *Та, грибы дороги.*

Вполне возможно, что "та" используется как дань украинскому языку, в котором это слово употребляется повсеместно (и тоже — в значении частицы или союза); возможно, что это стилизация под разговорный (просторечный) язык.